# How do I upload a transcript to YouTube via the API?

Tags: python, youtube-api

The relevant documentation is found here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_captions#Create_Caption_Track

I've tried the following, but I simply receive an esoteric "urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 401: Unknown authorization header"

```
import gdata.youtube, gdata.youtube.service, urllib2
yt_service = gdata.youtube.service.YouTubeService()
yt_service.ClientLogin("username@gmail.com","password")
yt_service.ProgrammaticLogin()
auth = yt_service.current_token.get_token_string()
url = "https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/VIDEO_ID/captions"
req = urllib2.Request(url, "Transcript", {'Content-Type': 'application/vnd.youtube.timedtext; charset=UTF-8', 'Content-Language:': 'en', 'Authorization': auth})
f = urllib2.urlopen(req)
```

Comment: The URL probably shouldn't contain `%20HTTP/1.1`.

Comment: You're right. I just tried it out and now have a new error. I'll update my question accordingly.

Comment: Try it with `'Authorization': 'Bearer '+auth` in the header

Comment: This time it's a "urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 401: Token invalid". So it seems I have the right request formatted, but I'm obtaining the authorization key incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a bunch of info in [this blog post](http://apiblog.youtube.com/2011/06/youtube-google-io-all-about-captioning.html), including a link to this [sample Python script](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-samples/source/browse/trunk/gdata/captions_demo.py) for uploading captions.

Comment: Excellent script -- thanks! I've uploaded some transcripts via the API and they are visible and correctly parsed on the my_videos_timedtext page and available in the player on the page, but they are not available on the watch page. Any idea why this is happening or how I could automatedly fix this? See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rrcFyORJdU8 for an example.